# Finding all 3x3 matrices that commute (when the minimal polynomial has an irreducible quadratic term)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to find all (real) $3 \times 3$ matrices that commute with a given (real) matrix T, also $3 \times 3$.

When T has a minimal polynomial composed of only linear factors this has been doable. [i.e., minimal polynomials of the form $m(x) = (x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)$ or $m(x) = (x-a_1)^2 (x-a_2)$ or $m(x)=(x-a)^3$][i.e., the matrix is in Jordan form, I think?]

In this case, I have been able to simply write $T \cdot \left( \begin{array}{ccc}a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array} \right) \cdot T$ and solve.

However, whenever the minimal polynomial has an irreducible quadratic factor, I have not been able to use this simple method successfully. I'm not going to even worry about the case when the minimal polynomial is irreducible cubic, if that exists. How then do I solve for all matrices that commute with T?

For example:

$T = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &2 \end{array} \right)$

I've found online that the minimal polynomial is $m(x) = (x^2 - x + 1)(x-2)$ and that the set of matrices is

$\left\lbrace \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & r \end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & r \end{array} \right) \right\rbrace$ with $r \in \mathbb{R}$

I have no idea how to get this. Using the brute force method above, I'm able to get the third row and third column, but not the rest.

Comment: Odd way to put this. Any polynomial in $T$ commutes with $T.$ By Cayley-Hamilton, any polynomial in $T$ can be re-written with specific degree bound, in this case $a_0 I + a_1 T + a_2 T^2.$ This need not be all: if $T=I,$ it actually commutes with everything, while polynomials in $I$ are just multiples of $I.$

Comment: I did it your original way, not that hard.

Comment: @WillJagy - thanks. So to be clear:

If we have a matrix $T$ which is $3 \times 3$, the set of matrices which commute with it are: $\{ A = a_0 I + a_1 T + a_2 T^2 | a_0, a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Is that correct? Thanks so much.

Comment: And are you saying that you were able to get a solution using the original method?

Comment: chi, yes, the original method. To correct you: the matrices that commute with $T$ INCLUDE $a_0I + a_1T + a_2 T^2$ in the 3 by 3 case. If you are careful, you can see how solving by the original method and writing out the polynomials above are actually the same answer. HOWEVER, those that commute COULD BE far more numerous.